# What do you use to express that the marker lines are visible on the other page

Tags: spoken-english

I drew something in pencil, then I outlined it with a black marker. Maybe it got too dark, and I could see the outline of that diagram on the other side of the page (when I turned the page.) I could see the impression on the other page. So what can I use,

> The diagram got impressed on the other side of the page .
>
> The diagram got printed on the other side of the page.

Do these sound natural? If not then what would sound natural?

Comment: The diagram **showed through** on (or to) the other side of the page.

Comment: Ok  Thank you:) @Michael Harvey

Comment: And what does "Ink bleeding through the page to the other side" mean @MichaelHarvey?  And I read "ghosting" for pages as well....

Comment: Can the present tense be used: The diagram in showing through on the other side.

Comment: "ink bleeding through" means the ink penetrated the paper.  "Ghosting" is when the ink is still wet and it imprints itself lightly onto the opposite page (ie you see p3 backwards on p2).  Yes, all tenses good including "showing through".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The ink bled through the page." - past tense

"The ink is bleeding through the paper". - present tense

Like any liquid, blood doesn't *always* penetrate the material it is on, but when you say "bled through", you always mean that the liquid passed through the material so it is visible on the other side.

"Ghosting" probably isn't appropriate here. Bled through is the perfect description.

The ink bled through to the back of the page.

The ink bled through onto the following page.

Comment: But what does "ghosting" mean anyway?

Comment: When a very faint copy of some undesired image shows up on the wrong page, or in the wrong place. It can happen for many different reasons besides too much ink. Since your problem deals specifically with ink penetrating the paper, "bleeding through" is the best, most precise way of describing the problem.

Comment: And if the image dosen't bleed through, for example I use a pencil a little too hard. I can see those words (not clearly) because the page has raised due to a lot of pressure.  What will be used in this context?

Comment: It left an impression on the next page. Or you could say a legible impression. (It's not exactly ghosting - ghosting would imply a slight amount of ink is forming the image)

Comment: So does "impression" sound natural?

Comment: In the context of "ink bleeding" can "impression" be used as well?

Comment: I would find 'impression' misleading if there is ink involved.

Comment: Maybe professional printers would use the word 'impression' to mean ink has been transferred. But most people would get confused. I expanded the original answer - that might help...

Comment: So it should be "ink bleeding" if ink's involved and "impression" will be used otherwise for "raised words on the other side of the page", right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94301/discussion-between-dwilbank-and-its-about-english).